# How to set Context.Provider value with data from server

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react so please take it easy on me.

All I am trying to do is set the Context.Provider value with data returned from a server (inside Main.js) & then access that context data from a child component (Home.js).

in the code block below I am setting the state with data returned from my server & adding to to my Context.Provider value in the render method.

**UserContext.js**

```
import React from 'react';
const UserContext = React.createContext(null);
export const UserProvider = UserContext.Provider;
export const UserConsumer = UserContext.Consumer;
export default UserContext;
```

**Main.js**

```
  constructor(props) {
    // axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:1010/';
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: {}
    };

      fetchUser = async () => {
        let jwt = localStorage.getItem('auth-jtw');
        let url = "http://localhost:8000/api/user";
        let headers =  {
          "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
          "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + jwt
        };
    
        let userData = await fetch(url, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: headers});
    
        let user = await userData.json()
        this.setState({ user });
      };
    
      componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchUser();
      }
```

and then use state.user inside my render() hook like the below:

```
 render() {
   
    // this is being called twice, the first time the user object is empty & the second it has data.
    console.log('USER:', this.state.user);

    return (
      <div>
        <UserProvider value={this.state.user}>
```

The problem is that the render method appears to be called twice, on the first call, this.state.user is a empty object & on the second call it has the user data returned from the server.

When I try access the user context in a child component(Home.js) it is returning a empty object, however I know that I am setting it correctly because if I hardcode  `<UserProvider value={this.state.user}>` to  `<UserProvider value="Test1234">` for example it is being returned in my child component

**Home.js** (child component where I am trying to pass the user via conext api from Main.js)

```
import React, { Component, useContext } from "react";
import Card from "../components/Card/Card.tsx";
import ClientLayout from './layouts/client/Client';
import  UserContext from "../contexts/UserContext";
class Home extends Component {
  static contextType = UserContext;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      const user = this.context;
  
      console.log('HOME PAGE USER IS: ', user);
```

Any help or guidance would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is happening because in your `Home.js` you are logging your `this.context` on `componentDidMount`, hence, you are only getting what the value of the context was when the `Home` component just mounted (this hook won't trigger again on context updates or re-renders).

Try running this code in `componentDidUpdate` or in `render` instead:

```
const user = this.context;
 
console.log('HOME PAGE USER IS: ', user);
```